# Ubuntu 17.10 keeps asking if I want to wait or quit

Tags: timeout

Since I updated to 17.10 Gnome, for several slow applications ubuntu keeps asking if I want to wait or force quit.  This is irritating and gets in the way, so I want to change the timeout. On a much slower laptop running xubuntu (xfce) 17.10 I do not have this problem.

Elsewhere ([How to increase waiting time for non responding programs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412917/how-to-increase-waiting-time-for-non-responding-programs/985511#985)) it was suggested that I'd have to edit the mutter app since it has a hard-coded timeout.

Is this really the only way to change this timeout?  I did make one attempt but the compilation came unstuck with an incompatible version of automake, and I don't really want to have to change the application anyway.

The applications that tend to do this are opening very large and complex spreadsheets in Libreoffice calc, and opening some complex forms in a remote database in Libreoffice Base.

Comment: This dialogue also seem to affect some functionality, as my mouse for instance won't take clicks inside a web browser when it is shown. Does anyone know if this is any better in 18.04?

Comment: It is same for 18.04. It would be great to have way to raise time for this...